# extension of real analytic function on $(0,\infty)$ and $[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

suppose we have given some function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which is real analytic. Suppose further there exists some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that  $f(x)=x^k$ for all $x\geq 0$ (or $x>0$). Does it follow that $f(x)=x^k$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$?

In the case of $x\geq 0$ it is possible to show that $f(x)=x^k$ in some neighborhood $x\in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$, $\epsilon>0$. But I have no idea about the other values $x\leq \epsilon$. Can someone help me?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f$ is real analytic, so $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty{a_nx^n}$ (on some neighborhood of $0$). But on $(0,\infty)$ we have that this is also given by $\sum_{n=0}^\infty{b_nx^n}$ where $b_n = \delta_{n,k}$.

Then apply the following:

> Suppose the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty{a_nx^n}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty{b_nx^n}$ converge in the segment $S=(-R,R)$. Let $E$ be the set of all $x\in X$ where the two series agree.  If $E$ has a limit point in $S$, then $a_n=b_n$ for all $n$.

Since $(0,\infty)$ certainly has a limit point in $\mathbb{R}$ (or in the relevant neighborhood of $0$), it follows that the two power series are identical, so $f(x) = x^k$ on all of $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$.

This only shows that $f(x) =x^k$ on $(-\epsilon,\infty)$, but we do notice that we've extended that set by a little bit, and we can effectively repeat the same argument ad infinitum to get it over all of $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Let $E = \{ x\in \mathbb{R} \mid f(x)=x^k\}$, so that $(0,\infty) \subset E$. Also, $E$ is closed. Let $F$ be the connected component of $E$ containing $0$. 
 We'd like for $F=E=\mathbb{R}$, but if not then $F=[a,\infty)$ for some $a$. But then $f$ analytic implies that it is equal to a Taylor series centered at $a$ on some neighborhood of $a$, and likewise we can express $x^k$ as a Taylor series centered at $a$; then since $[a,\infty)$ will contain a limit point of that neighborhood, our above result shows that $f(x) = x^k$ on the entire neighborhood. But then this shows that $(a-\delta,\infty) \subset E$ for some $\delta>0$, contradicting the hypothesis that $F$ was a connected component (recall that connected components are *maximal*, and we've contradicted the maximality). In fact, we've shown that the connected component cannot be bounded below, so $F=\mathbb{R}$. Since $F\subset E$, we find that $E=\mathbb{R}$.

(Statement and proof of the above result is Theorem 8.5 in Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your argument assumes that the radius of convergence is $\infty$ for the power series of $f$ around $0$. Is this necessarily the case?

Comment: Not at all; since $f$ is real analytic, $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty{a_n x^n}$ on some neighborhood of $0$, say $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$, and the same is true of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty{b_nx^n}$ as defined in my answer. $(0,\infty) \cap (-\epsilon,\epsilon) = (0,\epsilon)$ has a limit point.

Comment: Ok, but I do not quite understand why $f(x)$ has to be equal to $x^k$ for $x\leq \epsilon$. As far as I can see, your argument does not guarantee that.

Comment: Ah, I see your point. I've made an edit to show how to go from there